# Let $y=mx+h$ be Asymptote of the function $f$

Tags: calculus

Let $y=mx+h$ be Asymptote of the function $f$ .

And Suppose $$g(x)=af(bx+c)+d \ \ \ : \ \ a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$$

Now what is  asymptote of the function $g$ ?

Answer (score 2):

If $y=mx+h$ is asymptote of $f(x)$

the transformation is

$x:=bx+c$

$y:=ay+d$

which transforms $f(x)$ in $g(x)=af(bx+c)+d$

then to get the asymptote of $g(x)$ we apply the transformation to the asymptote $y=mx+n$ getting

$y=a(m(bx+c)+h)+d$

Comment: why ? Please prove it

Comment: Please see my edit